# Error in C#: "an expression tree may not contain a base access" - why not?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I was calling a method that accepts `Expression<Func<bool>>`.

As part of the expression I was passing:

```
this.Bottom == base.lineView.Top
```

The compiler gave me an error that

> an expression tree may not contain a base access

So I simply changed it to

```
this.Bottom == this.lineView.Top
```

because the member was protected anyway and now it works.

But this error really got me: why the heck would this `base` be a problem? Especially if using `this` instead will work but syntactically be the same result (same variable gets accessed)?

Comment: Interesting question. However, generally I never use the `base` keyword without reason. That is I only use it if the inherited member in `this` type is either overridden or hidden by a `new` member with the same name. Maybe for that reason I never ran into this issue with `base` in expression trees.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Looking at the [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation, I don't think there's an expression type which represents "base member access". Don't forget that even though in your case it meant the same as just `this`, in other cases it wouldn't:

```
class Test
{
    void Foo()
    {
        Expression<Func<string>> baseString = () => base.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "overridden value";
    }
}
```

Here that would represent a non-virtual call to `Object.ToString()` (for `this`). I can't see how that would be represented in an expression tree, hence the error.

Now that leads on to the obvious question of *why* there isn't a representation of non-virtual base member invocation in expression trees - I'm afraid I can't answer that part... although I can see that if you *could* build that expression programmatically, that would allow you to bypass normal polymorphism *from the outside* instead of only from inside the class itself (which is the normal case). That may be the reason. (Admittedly there are other ways of calling methods non-virtually, but that's a different matter, and I dare say there are situations where expression trees are "trusted" but other code isn't.)

Comment: Hey Jon, your conjecture is correct. See my answer for details.

Comment: @EricLippert: Great - it's always good to get confirmation :)

Comment: A perfect situation. Interesting question with great answers, thanks. My follow-up question. Are there any non-reflection/non-reflection.emit other ways to bypass polymorphism?

Comment: @PiotrZierhoffer: This is a question-and-answer site. If you have a new question, post a new question. That way (1) many people will try to answer it, and (2) it will more likely be found by people searching for answers to that question.

Comment: Sure thing. But I've just expected a "no". ;-)

Answer (score 41):

Jon's answer is correct. I want to follow up on Jon's comment:

> I can see that if you could build that expression programmatically, that would allow you to bypass normal polymorphism from the outside instead of only from inside the class itself (which is the normal case). That may be the reason

Suppose you have

```
public abstract class B // Prevent instantiation
{
    internal B() {} // Prevent subclassing outside the assembly. 
    public virtual void Dangerous() { ... } 
}
public sealed class D : B 
{ 
  public override void Dangerous() 
  { 
    if (!Allowed()) throw whatever;
    base.Dangerous();
  }
```

There should be no way for partially trusted code with a `D` in hand to call `B.Dangerous` on the instance of `D` without doing the safety check in `D.Dangerous`.

The CLR verifier therefore restricts you from performing a non-virtual invocation (a base invocation is of course non-virtual) on a virtual method from outside the class hierarchy. In fact, it goes even farther; you can't even perform that from a class nested within `D` ! (Of course if your program is granted the right to skip verification then you can do whatever you want; you can dereference arbitrary pointers to memory in unverifiable code which is a lot worse than making a static call on a virtual method.)

When we were designing expression trees we didn't want to deal with this messy security problem. The easiest thing to do was to simply make the whole thing illegal.

There were a number of other security problems with expression trees that could not so easily be solved, but those are a topic for another day.

Comment: I'll confess that in some situations I've made calls to private members via reflection. Indeed this is why we're told "private" is for your own protection even though it can be circumvented by consenting, sober adults. But now it appears calls to an overridden member may be entirely impossible under any circumstance. Is this the case?

Comment: @NJones: I should have been more clear. The CLR *verifier* restricts you from making such a call by failing to verify the method with the call. If your program is granted skip-verification permission then it can do so since the verifier doesn't run in the first place.