# How do I refer to a specific base class method in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

In .NET I am trying to monkey-patch a 3rd party library.  I created a new class, Grandchild, which inherits from a class Child derived from Parent.  In an override method of Grandchild, I need to skip Child and invoke Parent.  Is that possible?  In other words, I want to do:

```
public class Grandchild : Child {
    public void override MyMethod() {
        // illegal syntax examples, but how can I invoke Parent.MyMethod?
        base.base.MyMethod();  // nope...
        Parent.MyMethod(); // nope...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure inheritance is what you need?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method

Answer (score 6):

That simply cannot be done, not even with reflection, and for a very good reason - security.

If a class you distributed enforced some business rules, and clients were able to skip those rules, you could run into a huge security hole. Such basic polymorphism rules simply cannot be violated.

Security is also why expression trees cannot contain references to `base`, as explained by Eric Lippert [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22274464/857807).

```
//this is illegal
Expression<Func<string>> nonVirtualCall = () => base.Method();
```

Comment: The answers to the duplicate question give several methods for doing it.  There are no direct ways, but it is possible by one of several workarounds.